# Arduino water solar heater pump control

Tags: arduino

I am still a beginner, and I wanted to do this project

[image: project]

which will be fairly easy if I follow the code and the pic, but there is something I don't understand about the relay connection: Why is there a transistor, and why is there a diode, can't I just connect the output pin to a resistor then to the coil pin on the relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the transistor is there because the relay operates at 12V and probably wasnt over 100mA of current to operate. the arduino can't provide a signal of that magnitude so the transistor boots its output capability..

The diode is there because the relay contains an electromagnet, and an electromagnet is a type of inductor, and when you try to turn an inductor off it generates a high voltage, which could easily be hundereds of volts. but the `BC547` transistor is can only withstand a few tens of volts V<sub>ce</sub> when the transistor turns off the energy in the inductor forces the switched terminal more positive until it gets to 0.6V above the 12V supply and then the `iN4001` starts to conduct the current and he stored energy is burned off as heat in the electromagnet's resistance and in the diode's voltage drop. This is called a *freewheeling diode* or *catch diode*

All this complexity could be avoided by using a *solid-state relay* as they can be triggered directly by the arduino outputs but they can be quite expensive.

Comment: freewheel, flyback

Comment: seems this wheel has been reinvented many times, and consequently has many names.

Comment: so if i got a relay with a rated voltage less than 5V i can drop the transistor or i will still need it for the  freewheeling diode thing?

Comment: If the relay works with less than 20mA and a substantially lower voltage than 5V (check the datasheet for the microcontroller!) then it would work but still requires a diode. @user28324

Comment: actually i think it's 40 mA ( i will be using UNO ) 
thanks

Comment: @jippie last question please, is there something like maximum operating current for relays, like the max current in the high amperage circuit, and is the maximum switching current the maximum current in the low amperage circuit?

Comment: @user28324 I believe you are right about the 40 mA, but total package current is like 200 mA and the GPIO pin output voltage will drop to maybe 2.5 or 3 volts at best, again those details are all in the datasheet. Every relay that respects itself has basic ratings printed on it. Those are maximum ratings and it is bad design practice to use a device close to those ratings. Like the ATmega, a relay has a datasheet too.

Comment: the transistor is a 50c part(retail price for one $5 for 100),. finding a low power relay that has contacts tough enough to switch the pump is going to be hard. unless you go with a solid-state relay and then you will pay tens of dollars.

Comment: The diagram has a 10K resistor in the transistor base, I'd reduce that to 1K which will staturate te trransistor better san reduce heating in the transistor and probably help reliability.